# Display the monthwise financial year records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using below query to get the count, month name and amount but below query is displaying all the records available in the database. I have to display only financial year. like I have to show the data from `01-04-2020` to `31-03-2021`.

I want to know what query I have to change?

```
SELECT COUNT(f_id) as count
     , MONTHNAME(date_of_created) as month_name
     , sum(f_amt) as amount 
  FROM tbl_fileStatus 
 WHERE f_filestatus=1  
 GROUP 
    BY YEAR(date_of_created)
     , MONTH(date_of_created)
```

Comment: You are grouping by year but not filtering by year

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a date condition to your `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(f_id) as count,
       MONTHNAME(date_of_created) as month_name,
       SUM(f_amt) as amount 
FROM tbl_fileStatus 
WHERE  f_filestatus=1  
  AND date_of_created BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2021-03-31'
GROUP BY YEAR(date_of_created),MONTH(date_of_created)
```

To use a dynamic year, you could do something like:

```sql
SET @year = 2020
;
SELECT COUNT(f_id) as count,
       MONTHNAME(date_of_created) as month_name,
       SUM(f_amt) as amount 
FROM tbl_fileStatus 
WHERE  f_filestatus=1  
  AND date_of_created BETWEEN CONCAT(@year, '-04-01') and CONCAT(@year+1, '-03-31')
GROUP BY YEAR(date_of_created),MONTH(date_of_created)
```

If you wanted to pass the year in a parameter, you could replace @year with a placeholder in the above query.

Note that if you restrict the date period to a year or less you don't need to group by year, only month.

Comment: how do i set the year dynamic? I mean I don't want to change the year manually

Comment: @user9437856 see my edit, is that what you meant? or if you wanted to pass in a parameter, you could replace `@year` with a placeholder

Comment: Give me sometime to check the query

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thank you so much for the help.